# Scale child layout elements same as parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an Android application which will feature a compass face on which the azimuth position of the sun is displayed. The compass face is a 100x100 dp vector drawable which I scale with `match_parent` on both dimensions to fill the available screen area. The sun image is a 10x10 dp vector drawable which is overlaid on the compass image at the appropriate place. Both of them are inside a `ConstraintLayout`, also using `match_parent` scaling.

My problem is that I can't find any way to make the sun drawable scale by the same factor as the compass drawable. If I use `match_parent`, it expands to fill its parent layout. If I use `wrap_content`, it doesn't scale up at all, and is shown at much less than 1/10 the size of the compass face.

An excerpt from my layout file follows. Is there any straightforward way, either declaratively in the layout or in the associated Activity, to make the smaller drawable scale up by the same factor as its sibling compass face drawable?

A footnote: I'm using `app:layout_constraintCircle*` to position the sun drawable. I've resigned myself to having to scale `app:layout_constraintCircleRadius` in the app code, based on what little information I've been able to find. But if there's a way to make that scale with the compass face drawable too, that would be wonderful.

```xml
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/compass_composite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/compass_face"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_compass_display"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_compass_face"
            android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/compass_face"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="45dp"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="210"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sun"
            android:tint="@color/bg_noon"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: using percent-based layout width and height attributes. They require a lot of xml boilerplate, but once you churn that out, everything works very nicely. I still have to scale the circle-constraint radius by brute force, though. I'm hoping that either I find a better solution or that a future Android release provides a better way to do this.

By the way, these alleged "percent" values are actually decimal fractions -- so for example 1/10 is 0.1, not 10. I am unreasonably annoyed by this. :)

Here's an excerpt from my layout showing the trick:

```xml
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/compass_rotating"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/compass_face"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_compass_display"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_compass_face"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sun"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_sun_position"
                android:tooltipText="@string/content_sun_position"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_solid_dot"
                android:tint="@color/sun_yellow"
                app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/compass_face"
                app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
                app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="45dp"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```